# Listbox character limit per line

Tags: c#, listbox, limit

I have a listbox in my windows form application that shows quite long texts. Since texts are so long, user have to use the horizontal slider for check the rest of text.

So, I want to limit listbox character per line. For every 50 char it should go to next row, so user won't have to use glider.

I can't put "new line" since text source is Sql Database.

My code is basically this:

```
listbox1.items.add(dbRead["LongText"]); // dbRead = SqlDataReader
```

So I have to edit listbox itself. I've checked it a bit, but didn't manage to find. I've also tried to find an event like when text is changed, for every 50 char `listbox.items.add("")` etc.  I'm still alien to syntax.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried loading a string object with dbread then splitting it if it's more than 50 characters and adding each part to the listbox?

Comment: I haven't tried that. Nice, but what will happens if I have too much data. Speaking in Performance wise ?

Comment: The only extra overhead should be if the string is too long.  Since you won't have to iterate over the whole listbox you would actually be saving performance.

Comment: I didn't know how to split & trim etc. Since I'm programming for a week at most so this syntax kills me. I'll try your way too when I get used to syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an extension method(*SplitByLength*) like below

```
var input = "I have a listbox in my windows form application that shows quite long texts. Since texts are so long, user have to use the horizontal slider for check the rest of text.\nSo, I want to limit listbox character per line. For every 50 char it should go to next row, so user won't have to use glider.";
var lines = input.SplitByLength(50).ToArray();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

---

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static  IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string input, int maxLen)
    {
        return Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1," + maxLen + @"})(?:\s|$)")
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                    .Select(x => x.Trim());
    }
}
```

**----------EDIT----------**

After tinstaafl's comment, an edit seems to be a *must*

```
var input = "I have a listbox in my windows form application that shows quite long texts. Since texts are so long, user have to use the horizontal slider for check the rest of text.\nSo, I want to limit listbox character per line. For every 50 char it should go to next row, so user won't have to use glider.";
input = String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat(input, 100));

var t1 = Measure(10, () =>
{
    var lines = input.SplitByLength_LB(50).ToArray();
});

var t2 = Measure(10, ()=>
{
    var lines = input.SplitByLength_tinstaafl(50).ToArray();
});
```

---

```
long Measure(int n,Action action)
{
    action(); //JIT???
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        action();
    }
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

---

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static  IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength_LB(this string input, int maxLen)
    {
        return Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1," + maxLen + @"})(?:\s|$)")
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                    .Select(x => x.Trim());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength_tinstaafl(this string input, int maxLen)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        while (input.Length > 0)
        {
            output.Add(new string(input.Take(maxLen).ToArray()));
            input = new string(input.Skip(maxLen).ToArray());
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

And my results are different than yours: **11 ms. vs. 3384 ms.** :)

Comment: I was trying to make it happen but you already updated solution to working one :) It works very well. Thank you.

Comment: @OzanAyten Since you were asking about performance, you should be aware that the overhead on regex for something this simple has a huge impact on performance. In my tests it was by a factor of over 30.  I added alternative code and the test results.

Comment: 11 ms is Regex way to do it ?

Comment: @OzanAyten yes my tests say so (BTW: I don't say regex is the fastest way to do it. It is just the simplest way to do it(*at least according to me*))

Comment: @tinstaafl feel free to upvote if you think this answer is better than your deleted one :)

Answer (score 1):

Redid my code to take into account spaces.  With variable length lines some shorter some longer than 50 characters and the line breaks adjusted for spaces, I found that the performance is very close to the same. They're both between 15 and 25 milliseconds on 1000 strings.  Though regex does perform moderately faster. Here's the code I used:

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength_LB(this string input, int maxLen)
    {
        return Regex.Split(input, @"(.{1," + maxLen + @"})(?:\s|$)")
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                    .Select(x => x.Trim());
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength_tinstaafl(this string input, int maxLen)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>{""};

        string[] temp = input.Split("\n ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.Count(); i++)
        {
            if((output.Last() + " " + temp[i]).Length > 50)
            {
                output.Add(temp[i]);
            }
            else
                output[output.Count() - 1] += " " + temp[i];
        }
        return output;
    }
        return output;
    }
```

The test is like this:

```
        Stopwatch s1 = new Stopwatch();
        List<string> source = new List<string>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var input = "I have a listbox in my windows form application that shows quite long texts. Since texts are so long, user have to use the horizontal slider for check the rest of text. So, I want to limit listbox character per line.";
            int nextbreak = rnd.Next(20, input.Length);
            source.Add(new string(input.TakeWhile((x, y) => input.IndexOf(' ', y) <= nextbreak).ToArray()));
        }
        s1.Start();
        List<string> output = new List<string>(from s in source
                                               from p in s.SplitByLength_LB(50)
                                               select p);
        s1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("SplitByLength_LB\t" + s1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        s1.Reset();
        s1.Start();
        List<string> output2 = new List<string>(from s in source
                                                from p in s.SplitByLength_tinstaafl(50)
                                                select p);
        s1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("SplitByLength_tinstaafl\t" + s1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

Comment: `I found that the performance is very close to the same` I can't say the same. I copied your new code to my test case and found that regex solution is more than 10 times faster.

Comment: You're not testing the same thing.  The OP is getting variable length strings some longer than 50 some shorter than 50.  Your test only uses one length longer than 50.

Comment: No I used a random text taken from question. I just repeated it 100 times to get a *long* string.

Comment: Exactly and you only tested with one super long string instead of something closer to what the OP expects to receive.

Comment: Lets make it clear. Just post a text (as OP said it should be something long (`dbRead["LongText"]`)) so that we can make an objective comparison?

Comment: The text I used is in my post as well as the test.  The list of strings I used is made up of variable length strings from 20 characters to the full length of the source string, which is 216 characters.  Each string is truncated to a complete word

Comment: a) It is not a *long* text b) in your test you don't take JIT time into account. see my tests.

Comment: c) to make an objective test, just take an input string and run your code on it N  times. Running you code 1000 times on a short text doesn't mean the same.

Comment: didn't realize your the authority on what constitutes long.  In this case I consider it to be anything significantly longer than the required length.  Even putting my code in your tests the result are statistically close.  If the expectations are variable length strings then the test should be variable strings.

Comment: I think you are getting nervous. What is your problem. To make a scientific test, you should test the alternatives with the same conditions.

Comment: I tested my alternative and yours with exactly the same conditions.

Comment: No, Sorry that your test doesn't make sense. just get a sample text from a web site, say N bytes long. then Copy my test case (Remember the JIT case) and set the the text to *input*. then run your test again. I wait your results.

Comment: Simulating real world conditions makes plenty of sense.  You sound like the people testing saccharin by over feeding the mice more than one person would reasonably expect to eat in a lifetime.

Comment: **a)** About your code: No one can say that creating an iterator (`TakeWhile`) in a loop is a good idea. It's complexity is **N**2**  **b)** I see that continuing this discussion is meaningless since it seems that you can't follow what I try to say( of course it can be because of my poor english). It will be better for me to quit.

Comment: And lastly, Regex solution may not be the best performant one, and there may be many other alternatives, but your code is not the one of them. It is even not working correctly. For ex, test with `var input = "a\nb";` It should return **two** lines